# How to duplicate TImage component with the image using RTTI

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, rtti, timage

I know how to copy and duplicate a `TImage` component and others using RTTI.

But, I do not know if the image within the orginal `TImage`, that was loaded before, can be replicated along with the duplication.

Is it possible to duplicate the image inside the `TImage` *without* reloading the image into the new component after it is created?

Here is my code to find the PropType kind in the component to duplicate:

```cpp
PTypeInfo TypeInfo = static_cast<PTypeInfo>(Original->ClassInfo());

int PropCount = GetTypeData(TypeInfo)->PropCount;

for(int i = 0; i < PropCount; i++)
{
    switch ((*Prop->PropType)->Kind)
    {
        case tkInteger : ...
        case tkChar :
        case tkEnumeration :
        case tkSet :
        case tkWChar:
        case tkWString :
        case tkLString :
        case tkString:
        case tkFloat:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is an example to duplicate the `Height` from the original component to the newly created one:

```cpp
int OrdHeight = GetOrdProp(Original, "Height");
PropInfo = GetPropInfo((PTypeInfo)New->ClassInfo(), "Height");
SetOrdProp(New, PropInfo, OrdHeight);
```

How to duplicate the image? How to get the data of the image from the original `TImage` to the new `TImage`, and what is his `PropType->Kind` for helping get it and duplicating it?

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to duplicate the picture data is to `Assign()` the original `TImage::Picture` object to the new `TImage::Picture` object:

```cpp
NewImage->Picture->Assign(OrigImage->Picture);
```

You can use RTTI to obtain the 2 `TPicture*` object pointers.